# Add custom separator to ReSharper Type Members Layout

Tags: resharper

I'm testing the ReSharper "Type Members Layout" feature. See ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | Type Members Layout. And have found some [good guidelines online](http://exceptionz.wordpress.com/2007/06/10/resharper-30-member-re-ordering-settings/) and also read the [Jetbrains online documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Introduction__Help_on_Help.html). But adding a custom method separator I can't find out how.

Example:

```
//---- my custom method separator ----
public int Test()
{
  return 42;
}

//---- my custom method separator ---- 
public string Run()
{
  return "running";
}
```

So is it possible to include this in the custom "type members layout" xml code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in this version. It seems to me from the docs and playing with the options that `Type Members Layout` is solely for **reordering** and optionally **en-#region-ing and de-#region-ing** members in source files. I can't see anything which offers the possibility of adding arbitrary text.

You could perhaps look into using a regex-based Find/Replace operation that looked for

```
^\t\t\tpublic
```

(with the correct number of tabs so that only methods, not classes, would be matched) and inserted your method separator followed by a newline, before the found text.